# Parse String template instead of file in Pebble Template Engine

Tags: templates, kotlin, pebble

Is it possible to use the Pebble Template Engine to build up a template from a String instead of having to provide a filename?

```
val engine = PebbleEngine.Builder().build()
val writer = StringWriter();
engine.getTemplate("test.html").evaluate(writer);
```

Instead of providing `test.html`, how would I for example provide a template in the following format?

```
val template = "Hello {{world}} - {{count}} - {{tf}}"
```

I'm currently on Pebble 2.2.1

```
<!-- Pebble -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mitchellbosecke</groupId>
    <artifactId>pebble</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Solution** based on the answers I've received:

```
val context = HashMap<String, Any>()
... 
val engine = PebbleEngine.Builder().loader(StringLoader()).build();
val writer = StringWriter();
engine.getTemplate(template).evaluate(writer, context);
println(writer.toString());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According [to the tests](https://github.com/PebbleTemplates/pebble/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mitchellbosecke/pebble/ArraySyntaxTest.java#L29), you just need to set the engine up with a `StringLoader`:

```
val engine = PebbleEngine.Builder().loader(StringLoader()).build()
```

Comment: just as the Pebble repo finished checking out you answered, nooice!

Comment: This loader is not intended to be used in a production system; it is primarily for testing and debugging. Many tags do not work when using this loader, such as "extends", "imports", "include".

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply a [`StringLoader`](https://github.com/PebbleTemplates/pebble/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mitchellbosecke/pebble/loader/StringLoader.java) to the engine like so:

```
val engine = PebbleEngine.Builder()
    .loader(StringLoader())
    .build()

val writer = StringWriter()
engine.getTemplate("<p>{{name}}</p>").evaluate(writer, mapOf("name" to "Stack Overflow"))
val result = writer.toString() // "<p>Stack Overflow</p>
```